# Why element with z-index 0 is shown above element with z-index 1

Tags: css, position, z-index

I have following code (example):

```html
<div style="position: fixed">
  <div id="AAA" style="position: absolute; background-color: green; z-index: 1">AAA</div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative">
  <div id="BBB" style="position: absolute; background-color: red; z-index: 0">BBB</div>
</div>
```

For me it looks like AAA div should be shown over BBB div, because:

- they both have position specified and this position supports z-index
- AAA z-index (1) is higher than BBB z-index (0)

But in result HTML, BBB is shown over AAA. Why? Are there any document describing this behavior?

Comment: Remove the positioned outer divs and the inner divs would behave that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `position` and `z-index` on the parent starts a new stacking order. Specifically `position: fixed` on the first element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element in the following scenarios:
>
> ...
>
> Element with a position value "fixed" or "sticky" (sticky for all mobile browsers, but not older desktop).

So the child z-index of the first div is relative to the parent, not the rest of the document.

In this example, you want to apply z-index to the parent instead.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 1;">
  <div id="AAA" style="position: absolute; background-color: green; z-index: 1">AAA</div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div id="BBB" style="position: absolute; background-color: red; z-index: 0">BBB</div>
</div>
```